# Ubuntustudio 18.04 installation hang at 'saving installed packages'

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm hung up at saving installed packages during install of Ubuntustudio 18.04. Message is a loop stating

> ubuntu-studio ubiquity: unknown information field 'Original-Maintainer' in input data in entry in dpkg's status file

Does anyone have an answer(s)?

This is about the 5th attempt and it keeps hanging at different places. Last time it made it to

> copying file 135 of 135"

I started with freshly formatted/partitoned drives and reinstalled windows from previous image. Mint installed with virtually no issues - (I am using nomodeset for linux installs as I have an nividia graphics card) That was the only issue I had with Mint.

I've searched here and through Google and can't find any current or relevant answers.

The system is 64 bit i386 with 16Gb ram, 2 HD's a 500Gb (sda) & 750Gb (sdb).
Currently running windows 8.1 on sda1 & Linux Mint 19 on sdb3.

Previously had same Windows 8.1, Mint 18.?, and Studio 17.04 coexisting fine. 
Is there a way to get out of this loop and finish or am I going to have to start over AGAIN?

I'm certainly no Linux wizard and still fairly new at the system end of things.

Any help?

Comment: Hanging in *different* places each time is an important clue. The Ubuntu installer hasn't failed me in over 10 years and dozens of machines...assuming the ISO is clean, the USB is properly made, and the hardware is fully functional. Start carefully and methodically ruling out those possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the input. I verified shasum256 and gpg keys so ISO's fine (I think); burned to dvd and verified image and burn with k3b - it says OK - since I've gotten so far a couple of time, should I try to mount partition and check what's there? or maybe update grub to see if it will boot? Thanks, Scott